# How can I ensure that an object only belongs to one collection, while maintaining the DRY principle?

Tags: php, design-patterns, collections

I'm trying to solve a problem in my PHP code, but this is also something I've been unable to solve in other code as well.

I have an object that must belong to one and only one collection.  And I will primarily be accessing these objects from the perspective of the collection.  Other code wouldn't be expected to find the Object without going through the Collection.

So, how I've handled this in the past would be to give the Object a reference to the Collection. In this way, we attempt satisfy that the Object can only belong to one Collection.  Then I would add the Object to the Collection.

```
public function __construct(Collection $c)
{
    $this->setCollection($c);
}

public setCollection(Collection $c)
{
    $this->collection = $c;
    $c->addObject($this);
}
```

This is an obvious contradiction to "Don't Repeat Yourself". And comes about because the requirements of, needing easy access to the collection of objects and requiring objects only belong in one collection, are at odds with each other.  The Object knows it's in the Collection and the Collection knows the Object is in it the collection. If either gets out of sync the system is broken.

And the problems become obvious when you start trying to make code to move an object from one collection to another. Or when deleting an object.

So, has anyone found a solution to this kind of problem? Is there something I should try?  In the end I can make it work with a lot of double checking, but it seems like there has to be a better way.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I follow your line of reasoning to the end game of 'double checking'... but what's wrong with code like this?

```
class Collection {

   public function AddMember(Member $m) {
       $m->SetCollection($this);
       // add to underlying data structure
   }

   public function RemoveMember(Member $m) {
       // remove from underlying data structure
   }
}

class Member {
    private $collection = null;

    public function SetCollection(Collection $c) {
        if($this->collection)
            $this->collection->RemoveMember($this);
        $this->collection = $c;
    }

    public __destruct() {
        if($this->collection)
            $this->collection->RemoveMember($this);
    }
}
```

Syntax is probably off, treat it as psuedo-code, not tested, use references where needed, other disclaimers etc.

This is a great design pattern where friend classes/methods would be useful for proper encapsulation, to prevent anyone other than a collection object from setting or removing a member from its collection. You will also want to think long and hard about which methods you want to be used as the entry points and do the right thing in those cases without falling into a recursion loop. For a framework/library class like this, unit tests will make your life much easier.

Yeah, I can see where you may be worried about having to do an `if` check before basically doing anything with adding, removing or destroying. But that's the nature of a smart & safe pointer/reference pattern. The DRY principle isn't so much about avoiding redundancy of safety checks as it is about avoiding having multiple copies of data or redundant implementations of algorithms. Yes, each of those methods in my pseudo code is technically an algorithm, but here's a few things to chew on (okay, they're really the same-ish thing, stated from different perspectives):

1. They run in constant time (provided you avoid the recursion pitfalls I mentioned).
2. Seriously: shortest algorithm ever.
3. If you're worried about optimizing out half of your `if` statements in a library, you're missing the forest for the (a single) tree. Optimization time is better spent on making the code easier to use, easier to maintain, and reducing the complexity of algorithms. It doesn't get any less complex than a constant time algorithm.
4. You're not going to peg your processor by doing an extra `if` statement on every add or remove. You peg your processor by running an `O(n^2)` algorithm on a large `n`.

To sum up, no there really isn't a better way to implement a safe, doubly-linked data structure. You have to check the safety on each link and that's the the way it's going to be.

Comment: The `if`s come from accessing the Members from the Collection. Imagine a `$collection->getMembers()` and the function iterating through all its members `if($member->getCollection != $this) //prune member`. I've considered a combination of what you have here, with an observer pattern so the Collection watches for a change to the Member and prunes itself on a change. My concern is probably best stated as "Added complexity, leads to more chances for trouble."

Comment: Also, there isn't a `friend` visibility in PHP. So I'd need to do manual checks to ensure someone hasn't done something wrong. Can't rely on the system to keep them from breaking things.

Comment: I don't think you need to check on access. If you properly control the add & remove methods on both the member and the collection objects, then you are assured the collection is always in a good state. As for the manual checks, I agree the classes need to perform checks on modifications, but you really don't need to go overboard on them.